# Execute c# console application with Selenium from SSIS

Tags: c#, sql, selenium, ssis, agent

I have a C# console application that uses a Selenium NuGet package. This process opens some URLs and saves any data from the pages in a SQL Server.

The question is when I execute only the c# app its works fine.

Then I create an SSIS package and a script task in SSIS and call this c# app.

Again when I execute from SSIS its works fine but when I schedule the SSIS package from SQL Agent the process shows that it's running but never start and never finish.

Does anybody have an idea if I have to change anything?

Regards!

**EDIT:**

This is the detail of my development.

[Solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gUWV.png)

My SSIS solution contains only one dtsx in which I create 2 steps

[The blue step is the c# develop that use Selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDXby.jpg)

The first step is a script that sends a mail indicating the process is starting.

The second step is a process task that executes "Scrap.exe". Scrap.exe is the c# develop that use Selenium to scrap some urls. When I run this solution from Visual Studio the result is successful.

Then I create the job in the SQL Agent (SQL Server 2016). This job has only one step that executes the dtsx.

[This is the job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pqPy.png)

Finally, when I execute this job (right click -> start job at step) the job run correctly but never finish.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDLYg.png)

Sorry for my English I'm from Argentina.

Comment: There are many things that can go wrong, so to diagnose your issue please provide some additional information: Are you using logging to track the status of your tasks? If not, two ways to implement logging are to log directly via a script task or by using SSIS>Logging in the toolbar. Have you received any errors when you run through the agent? What version of SQL Server are you deploying on and what target version are you using in your SSIS package? Did you convert your package for "package deployment" before deploying?

Comment: Hi BenG! Thanks about your reply! I edit the post bring you more information. I try to convert the package for "package deployment" but nothing happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Agent account is a non-user (Service) account, therefore doesn't have access to active Desktop Session to do any interaction.

There is no way to "Interaction with Desktop" from non-user Windows accounts
since Windows 6.1 (Longhorn, Vista), even if you run SQL Agent under your Windows Account and enable "Interact with Desktop", you'll get the same result, as it considered as a security hole,

You might need to create a Windows Application which gets the requests from SSIS and handle and respond back to DB,
This application needs to be initiated on a real user account and the session has to stay open,

Keep in mind that user can lock the screen but cannot log-off as the application will get closed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm going to try to replicate the SSIS package in C # code and scheduleit with the windows task scheduler.